# Constructor for BinarySearchTree <T extends Comparable<? super T>> to avoid bound missmatch error?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, comparable

I was creating an Object in my mainclass

```
SearchTreeInterface < MyClass > object = new BinarySearchTree <MyClass> ();
```

and I got this error:

```
 Bound mismatch: The type MyClass is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>> of the type SearchTreeInterface<T>
```

I remember I had this error before when I was using Array List the same way and
my fix was to change the declaration in my constructer by adding `new Comparable` Like this:

```
public ArrayList(int size){
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    T[] temp = (T[]) new Comparable[size];
    list=temp;
    numberOfEntries = 0;

}
```

How can I do the same for my BinarySearchTree Constructors?

this is how they currently look like:

```
 public BinarySearchTree ()
{
    super ();
} // end default constructor


public BinarySearchTree (T rootEntry)
{
    super ();
    setRootNode (new BinaryNode < T > (rootEntry));
} // end constructor
```

where and how should I add `new Comparable` to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyClass` needs to extend `Comparable`, so it should look like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Comparable<MyClass> {}
```

(`Comparable` enables class to be sorted inside lists, etc)

And you will also need to add a function `int compareTo(T o) {}` which returns:

```
-1 if the current instance should be listed before o
 0 if the current instance equals o
 1 if the current instance should be listed after o
```

(you might need to switch -1 & 1, not 100% sure on that :))